# Inline list heights not consistent with wrapped text

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Hi I have an inline list which is behaving strangely if the text in the anchor wraps onto the next line. I can solve it with `line-height: 0;` but this also messes up the text. Any ideas on how to get them all on the same line?

[image]

**Code snippet**

```css
#communityBoardsLinks{ margin: 10px 0 20px 0; list-style: none; padding: 0;}
#communityBoardsLinks li{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
}
#communityBoardsLinks li a{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#communityBoardsLinks li a:hover{ color: red;}
#communityBoardsLinks li:last-child{ width: 115px;}

#wrapperMan{ width: 715px;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapperMan">
 <ul id="communityBoardsLinks">
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Long Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Long Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Long Link</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` in `#communityBoardsLinks li`.

```css
#communityBoardsLinks{ margin: 10px 0 20px 0; list-style: none; padding: 0;}
#communityBoardsLinks li{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#communityBoardsLinks li a{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#communityBoardsLinks li a:hover{ color: red;}
#communityBoardsLinks li:last-child{ width: 115px;}

#wrapperMan{ width: 715px;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapperMan">
 <ul id="communityBoardsLinks">
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Long Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Long Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Long Link</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You most welcome bro my pleasure. P.S: Don't forget to accept the answer :)